# Not displaying first option in select Element?

Tags: angularjs

Not displaying first option in select Element?
Here drop down list starting with empty option.Why i am not getting first option as o index of array? 
    Why does angularjs include an empty option in select
how to use ng-option to set default value of select element
Customized select element options in AngularJS
how to display option as selected in select box in angularjs?
Obtaining the selected option in a select element with AngularJS
First selection of  element not working in IE
selected element in ng-options with array
How to select first select option after filtering in Angular
Display unlisted value in select with ng-options
displaying a selected value with ng-options angularjs
How to set a selected option of a dropdown list control using angular JS
How to select first element in select list Angular JS?
how to make the first option active in ng-select coming inside ng-repeat

```
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<select ng-model="selected" ng-init="a" >
<option  ng-repeat="a in ['CSE','ECE','CHEM','MME','CE']">{{a}}</option>
</select>
<p>{{selected}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in your app.js file ,  assign default value to selected , i.e. $scope.selected = 'CSE';

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign selected in order for it to select the option of your choice. In your code, selected is null/undefined and therefore your first option won't be selected.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/35YBCPVH5SJijfP8cZoZ?p=preview) is how I usually solve this problem:

**js**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.arr = ['CSE','ECE','CHEM','MME','CE'];
});
```

**html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selected" ng-init="selected = arr[0]" >
    <option  ng-repeat="a in arr">{{a}}</option>
    </select>
    <p>{{selected}}</p>
</body>
```

In ng-init I assign selected to be the first element of the array, this will make this option be selected by default.